# The project was not built due to "ProjectXX does not exist".

Tags: eclipse, build, build.gradle, jboss7.x, myeclipse

I am trying to set up a workspace in MyEclipse. And I am getting 20 errors with the same description as below.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built due to "ProjectXX does not exist". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent ProjectXX       Unknown Java Problem

Now I can see that this project, ProjectXX is clearly in my workspace and it is a EAR project. My team does not face this issue in their MyEclipse/PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why, but this resolved my issue. I selected the option to import existing Gradle project into workspace and then gave the exact root folder of the project and then the errors were gone. [image: Gradle Fixes project issues]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was to deactivate the "Java Builder" property. To do it, just open the project properties with right click, go to "Builders" and deactivate "Java Builder". You can now delete the errors, validate the project and the problem is never seen again.

Thanks to @Tony Weddle for the hint "the EAR is not a Java Project".